# Prove that $1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{nm}}\leq \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{m}}}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

For what values of the real parameter $\alpha$ the following inequality is true?
$$1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{nm}}\leq \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{m}}}$$
for each $n,m\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $$1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{nm}}\leq \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{n}}}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{1+\frac{\alpha}{m}}}$$

Coverts to:
$$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+mn}\le\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha +m}}\sqrt{\frac \alpha{\alpha+n}}$$
Or if $\alpha\ne0$ we can cancel it and get:
$$(\alpha+m)(\alpha+n)\le(\alpha+mn)^2\\
\alpha^2+(m+n)\alpha+mn\le \alpha^2+m^2n^2+2\alpha mn\\
\alpha\ge\frac{mn(mn-1)}{m+n-2mn}$$
Anyways $\alpha=0$ is a solution too. And $\alpha\ge0$ since we have it in squareroots.

Comment: @Macavity yes because $\sqrt{x}$ is defined for $x\ge0$. also when $m=1$ $\alpha\le-1$ so $\alpha\in\phi$ or there's no possible range for $\alpha$ or the inequality is a contradiction in that case of $m=1$.

Comment: @Macavity that's because we canceled $\alpha$ on both sides and it won't hold if $\alpha=0$

Comment: @Macavity: I didn't notice the sign issues at first sight. Anyway the proof can be fixed easily, so I do not retract my upvote, also because I do not like people downvoting for the only sake of pointing out minor flaws.

Comment: @Macavity is it correct now?

Comment: @Macavity now?.

Comment: @Macavity please edit it according to what you wish, this way would be better, rather than me doing some random edits.

Comment: It's best if you edit it, or let it remain as it is - I think there is enough already in the post to guide towards the correct answer.